# EXIF data from image using javascript and phonegap to fix orientation

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, base64, exif

I am using phonegap and javascript to capture an image and display the image. The orientation is wrong when displayed on my android device. Having done some research I came across two JS files binaryajax.js and exif.js. I am trying to use this to change the orientation of the image by changing the EXIF data but it is not working. I get an empty string returned from pretty function in exif.js which takes an image as a parameter and displays properties of image. So I tried decoding the image and using other functions to 
display exif data but still it is not working, I either get undefined or false.

```
  function captureCameraPic() {
   // Take picture using device camera
   var camera = navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraPicSuccess, onCameraPicError,
        {
            quality: 80,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL

        });

  }


 function onCameraPicSuccess(imgData)
 {
        document.getElementById('tempImg').src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgData;
        document.getElementById('tempImg').onload = function()
        {
         alert(document.getElementById('tempImg').src);
         var b64 = document.getElementById('tempImg').src;
         var bin = window.atob(b64.split(',')[1]);
         alert(b64);
         var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(bin)); 
         alert(exif.Make);
         alert(EXIF.pretty(document.getElementById('tempImg')));
        }
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Have you got any solution?